# Error ocultando los td en mi tabla

Tags: jquery, css, html5, html-tabla

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente tabla en donde mis td padres por asi decirlos les puse la clase **galleta grande** y para cada hijo opte por ponerle **galleta chica**.

Lo que buscaba hacer es que al darle click al + se mostraran sus hijos y al darle otro se ocultaran.
Pero lo unico que logre es que en el caso de que sean más de uno solamente el primero se oculte

```js
//Esta es la funcion con la que oculto los TD
$("tr.Galleta_Grande").click(function () { 
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            $(this).next("tr.Galleta_Chica").toggle();
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered " style="width:100%">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <th>ÁREA</th>
                                <th>Enero</th>
                                <th>Febrero</th>
                                <th>Marzo</th>
                                <th>Abril</th>
                                <th>Mayo</th>
                                <th>Junio</th>
                                <th>Julio</th>
                                <th>Agosto</th>
                                <th>Septiembre</th>
                                <th>Octubre</th>
                                <th>Noviembre</th>
                                <th>Diciembre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="Galleta_Grande" id="1"><td><a style="color:purple;cursor:pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td><td>Dirección</td><td>0</td><td>61</td><td>50</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="Galleta_Chica" style=""><td></td><td>Livia Albarrán Perales</td><td>0</td><td>11</td><td>50</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="Galleta_Chica"><td></td><td>Crescencio  Aguilar Tapia</td><td>0</td><td>50</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="Galleta_Grande" id="8"><td><a style="color:purple;cursor:pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td><td>Indicadores</td><td>100</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="Galleta_Chica"><td></td><td>Reyna Aurora Aguilar Tapia</td><td>100</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="Galleta_Grande" id="21"><td><a style="color:purple;cursor:pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td><td>Recursos Financieros</td><td>0</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr class="Galleta_Chica"><td></td><td>Raul Alfonso Amaya Bucio</td><td>0</td><td>20</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Total General</th>
                                <th>Enero</th>
                                <th>Febrero</th>
                                <th>Marzo</th>
                                <th>Abril</th>
                                <th>Mayo</th>
                                <th>Junio</th>
                                <th>Julio</th>
                                <th>Agosto</th>
                                <th>Septiembre</th>
                                <th>Octubre</th>
                                <th>Noviembre</th>
                                <th>Diciembre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Tengo dos preguntas

**1.-¿Comó puedo ocultar todos los td hijos del padre ?**

**2.-¿Comó se podrian tener ocultos por default los hijos?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te anexo la siguiente solución de acuerdo a los puntos que mencionas:

1.-¿Comó puedo ocultar todos los td hijos del padre ?

R: Agregando una dependencia de los hijos con los padres, para ésto simplemente en su clase agregaremos el id del padre.

2.-¿Comó se podrian tener ocultos por default los hijos?

R: Anexando desde el inicio que los hijos estén ocultos gracias a la clase en común.

Anexo el código en solución a tu problema

En el lado del Jquery utilicé tu estructura de llamar a las funciones agregando un toque de estética al momento de ocultarlas.

Anexo el compilador para ser visualizado:

```js
$("tr.Galleta_Chica").hide(); 
  
    $("tr.Galleta_Grande td").click(function () { 
   var idOfParent = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
   $('tr.'+idOfParent).toggle('slow');
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.2/jquery-confirm.min.css">
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered " style="width:100%" > 
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <th>ÁREA</th>
                                <th>Enero</th>
                                <th>Febrero</th>
                                <th>Marzo</th>
                                <th>Abril</th>
                                <th>Mayo</th>
                                <th>Junio</th>
                                <th>Julio</th>
                                <th>Agosto</th>
                                <th>Septiembre</th>
                                <th>Octubre</th>
                                <th>Noviembre</th>
                                <th>Diciembre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="Galleta_Grande" id="1">
                         <td><a style="color:purple;cursor:pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td>
                         <td>Dirección</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>61</td>
                         <td>50</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr class="1 Galleta_Chica" style="" > <!--Observa que en su clase tiene en común el id del padre-->
                         <td></td>
                         <td>Livia Albarrán Perales</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>11</td>
                         <td>50</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="1 Galleta_Chica" > <!--Observa que en su clase tiene en común el id del padre-->
                         <td></td>
                         <td>Crescencio  Aguilar Tapia</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>50</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                         <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="Galleta_Grande" id="8">
                         <td>
                          <a style="color:purple;cursor:pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td>
                          <td>Indicadores</td>
                          <td>100</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr class="8 Galleta_Chica" > <!--Observa que en su clase tiene en común el id del padre-->
                          <td></td>
                          <td>Reyna Aurora Aguilar Tapia</td>
                          <td>100</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr class="Galleta_Grande" id="21"><td><a style="color:purple;cursor:pointer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a></td>
                          <td>Recursos Financieros</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>20</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr class="21 Galleta_Chica"> <!--Observa que en su clase tiene en común el id del padre-->
                          <td></td>
                          <td>Raul Alfonso Amaya Bucio</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>20</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                          <td>0</td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Total General</th>
                                <th>Enero</th>
                                <th>Febrero</th>
                                <th>Marzo</th>
                                <th>Abril</th>
                                <th>Mayo</th>
                                <th>Junio</th>
                                <th>Julio</th>
                                <th>Agosto</th>
                                <th>Septiembre</th>
                                <th>Octubre</th>
                                <th>Noviembre</th>
                                <th>Diciembre</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>




                
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias todo funciono perfecto  y ese efecto que le agregaste lo hace ver mucho mejor

Comment: De nada amigo, un placer apoyarte, edité mi respuesta anexando el compilador para que pueda ser visualizado por otros usuarios.